# How can I load multiple nib files in one CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This only loads `DescriptionImageSliderCollectionViewCell`. I pretty sure what is going on here, but I want to load both but I don't know how to do so.

My code to register collection view cell:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nibFile : UINib =  UINib(nibName: "DescriptionNearCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)

    descriptionCollectionView.register(nibFile, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "descriptionCell")

    let nibFile2 : UINib =   UINib(nibName: "DescriptionImageSliderCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)

    descriptionCollectionView.register(nibFile2, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "descriptionCell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Dequeue Reusable Cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "descriptionCell", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You can't register more than one nib on a CollectionView with the same reuseIdentifier.

Comment: @brandonscript i can do it tableview?

Comment: Not with the same reuseIdentifier you don't

Comment: @brandonscript  should i use different nib file for different reuseIdentifier? whatever CollectionView  or TableView

Comment: Use a unique reuseIdentifier for each nib, yes.

Comment: @brandonscript thank you so much . i will accept your answer. if you give

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't register more than one nib on a CollectionView with the same reuseIdentifier. Use a unique one for each:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nibFile : UINib =  UINib(nibName: "DescriptionNearCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)

    descriptionCollectionView.register(nibFile, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "descriptionCell")

    let nibFile2 : UINib =   UINib(nibName: "DescriptionImageSliderCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)

    descriptionCollectionView.register(nibFile2, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "descriptionCell2")
    // This >>                                                                               ^
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (youWantCellOne) {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "descriptionCell", for: indexPath)
    } else {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "descriptionCell2", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the correct naming convention "descriptionCell2" or "DescriptionCell2"? if  you tell me i will glad . thanks

Comment: There is no correct naming convention; you can make your own and stick to it (or not)

Comment: It is giving crash: 'Could not load NIB in bundle...'

Comment: Sounds like your bundle id is incorrect, but please open a new question to get a proper answer.